# How to chain function against a non-class TypeScript object

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia

I have some Vue3 (CompositionAPI) code in a Pinia store but this is more specifically a TypeScript question.

The code looks like this:

```
export const useCommonStore = defineStore("commmon", () => {

const commonState = reactive({
    isRequestLoading: false,
    lookupsLoaded: false,
    lineOfBusinesses: LookupItem[]
    )};

    
export const emptyOption = {value: 0, name: "No selection"};


const withEmptyOption = (options: Array<ILookupItem>) => {
    return [emptyOption, ...options];}

}
```

To use this elsewhere (e.g. in a Vue component) I have code that looks like this:

```
commonStore.withEmptyOption(commonStore.commonState.lineOfBusinesses)
```

and I don't like it. I would rather have

```
commonStore.state.lineOfBusinesses.withEmptyOption()
```

but I cannot see how to do this! Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Is `withAllOption` in your code supposed to be the same as `withEmptyOption`? Regardless, `lineOfBusinesses` would need to be an object containg both of the `LookupItem[]` array and the `withAllOptions` function so you can access both.  Or you can create a more specific [getter](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/getters.html) that works just on the array in question rather than taking in any array as a param, `lineOfBusinessesWithAllOptions() { return [ emptyOption, ...lineOfBusinesses ] } `

Comment: @yodah sorry, that was a cut and paste issue but for this example yes, they are the same (in terms of intent). I fixed the sample code

Comment: @yodah there are various other arrays in that state and what I want to do is avoid having multiple getters, one for each of the arrays. Each of the areas can be used as follows:  1. simply as it is, 2. with an "All" option and 3. with a "Empty" option

Comment: to be able to call a function on an array, the [Array object definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#static_methods) itself must contain the function, which by default contains some you're probably aware of, `find()`, `filter()`, `sort()`, etc.  You _can_ add new custom functions to the Array _prototype_ object, but I'd say it's not the recommended go-to solution when other solutions are possible...

Answer (score 0):

You could access the value from within the store using `this`

```js
interface CommonStoreState {
  isRequestLoading: boolean;
  lookupsLoaded: boolean;
  lineOfBusinesses: LookupItem[];
}
export const useCommonStore = defineStore("commmon", {
  state:(): CommonStoreState => ({
    isRequestLoading: false,
    lookupsLoaded: false,
    lineOfBusinesses: [],
  )},
  getters: {},
  actions: {
    withAllOption(): void {
      console.log('lineOfBusinesses', this.lineOfBusinesses);
    },
  }
});

    
export const emptyOption = {value: 0, name: "No selection"};


const withEmptyOption = (options: Array<ILookupItem>) => {
    return [emptyOption, ...options];}

}
```

*somewhere else*

```js
commonStore.withAllOption();
// Log (commonStore.ts, ln 15)
// > lineOfBuisnesses: [...]
```

Comment: The `state` is defined here the same as the Option Store in the Pinia docs, which allows you to access the values and methods through dot notation without specifying a special state variable and calling it reactive. See [Pinia Defining a Store, Option Stores](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/##Option-Stores). The Option and Setup stores are interchangeable depending on your usage.

Comment: I have a preference for the setup store for code consistency but my comments above apply here, there are several different arrays in the state so I want to be able to choose one and then chain the withAllOptions() onto that